# How can I install a pendant light fixture on a cathedral ceiling with no attic space?

Tags: electrical, lighting

My house has an integrated ceiling/roof with exposed rafters... the ceiling/roof is sloped and surfaced with V-edged 2" redwood boards over 4x6 rafters 4' on center.  I want to hang a pendant light over the dining room area (unfortunately right in between two rafters).  Do I need to mount raceway to a surfaced-mounted junction box? What type of junction box exisst for this implementation (that doesn't look like a rough piece of hardware)?

Comment: A picture might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to lots of [images of a variety of surface wiring hardware](http://www.google.com/search?q=surface+wiring+systems&hl=en&rlz=1G1GGLQ_ENUS302&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=n6teUc6WOKzA4AOOvoF4&ved=0CHUQsAQ&biw=1378&bih=815).  There are several manufacturers of good looking surface boxes and raceways. One of the popular high quality makers is Wiremold.

Comment: thanks so much... great ideas... sara Tester101 shirlock homes... special thanks to @HerrBag for all the images - very helpful... Since the previous owners painted the ceilings, I'll be repainting. It should be relatively easy to embed the wiring up to the J box and caulk/paint to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

I think a redwood cove molding

[image]

(like a crown, its a sprung molding, installed at a 45, with open space behind) to hide the wire running up from the wall, installed on the side of the 4x6 rafter.  Then reate a minibeam (Attach a top piece across the whole joist bay, then add a 3 sided box that slides over the top piece) that has unequal legs, to create a level spot to attach the pendant hardware.  The angled beam would run from side to side.  Encase a junction box sitting on an angled block that matches the slope of the ceiling.

If you can rout out enough space for the cable in the ceiling boards, a flush mount fixture might work.

[image]  [image]

If you don't do this yourself, you'll need both and electrician and a finish carpenter.

Answer (score 0):

Have a channel plunge-routed up the side of the beam/rafter. Run the Romex through the channel. Cover with a matching piece of flat redwood the width of the beam, a quarter inch or half inch thick sister board is all you need, it's just to cover the channel and wire. Also route out a shallow pancake J-box space at the nearest point to where the drop will be for the light fixture. A hole drilled in the sister board where the wire comes out of the J-box will remove the need for an unsightly box cover. The sister boards should be installed with small screws or finishing nails which will allow you to gently pry up the board to service the wiring if needed. Use a chain and hook to loop the cord over and down to the location you desire. If the chain annoys you you can cover it with a fabric sleeve, ruched up over the chain and wire. I have done installations like this in a number of arts and crafts homes and it has worked well and looked really nice.